# how to get html tags of page without URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to save the HTML tags of whole page that is going to (render) client side in the database table with a unique id so next time I can fetch that page directly from database with id and without any complicate logic execution. All this without any URL means I don't want to pass a URL to any method that will get the HTML tag. I want to get HTML tags  before even rendering the page because I have some status system once status changed that URL will not work.

Sorry if my question is not clear, but I tried to mention all details. I simply want HTML tag of my view before sending it to client so that I can save those tags with a unique id in database table and next time I can just fetch those tags from the database table with that unique id. My need is that the view contains many complex queries that I don't want to run each time.

It's a kind of certificate in that once it is printed, it cannot be changed, it can only be viewed by that unique ID in a faster way.

Comment: You question is very unclear, can you please try to clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: You know, there are pre-made solutions for content caching...

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it sounds like you want to go through a whole lot of work, to include a trip to a database, to save yourself a small amount of code-to-HTML rendering.  I don't think this is going to achieve what you want it to achieve.

Comment: I agree. Your question isn't clear. perhaps an example of what you want to store might help. this sounds like a caching question, but we need more from you.

Comment: Surely using page output caching will be even better. No page logic execution or database calls. http://rbonini.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/note-to-self-use-outputcache-in-mvc-3/

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear but tried to mention all details i simply want html tag of my view before sending it to client

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called output caching, use that instead.

If you need to save the HTML output, you need to add an action filter and intercept the `Result` and save the text in database.

Comment: ok, i have never used output cache before in my app i know page can be cache on server and client but if i will use this will this give me all html tags which is before going to client ?